# How to override equals for alias types in scala

Tags: scala, overriding, equals

I am using a type alias like below:

```
trait IPAddress
object IPAddr {
  type IP = Array[Byte] with IPAddress
  type IPv4 <: IP
  type IPv6 <: IP
}
```

Here I want to override the `equals` method for type `IP`. How can that be done?

Comment: Can you describe how are you gonna use this code afterwards ?

Comment: Right now if I have 2 instances of IP, and I use "==" they return false even though the array elements are same. So instead I need to do a.deep == b.deep for comaparing. I want to override the equals method for the type so that I need not append ".deep" in later comparisons.

Comment: Could you this code where you create instances and do comparison ?

Comment: Since the type IP is actually a byte array, when I compare two instances of IP say a and b with a == b, it returns false as it tries to compare the references and the objects are different. But a.deep == b.deep equals as expected. i want to override equals so that while comparing a, b of type IP the custom equals method is called which compared the deep copies.

Comment: I do not understand how do you create an instance of IP. Sample code please.

Comment: val ipInstance : IP = InetAddress.getByName("1.2.3.4").getAddress().asInstanceOf[IP]

Comment: Sounds like you really want some sort of wrapper around that class, then.

Answer (score 3):

Below solution is done with extension method `===`:

```
  implicit class IPOps(ip: IP) {
    def ===(other: IP): Boolean = ip.sameElements(other)
  }

  trait IPAddress
  object IPAddr {
    type IP = Array[Byte] with IPAddress
    type IPv4 <: IP
    type IPv6 <: IP
  }

  val ip1 = InetAddress.getByName("1.2.3.4").getAddress.asInstanceOf[IP]
  val ip2 = InetAddress.getByName("1.2.3.4").getAddress.asInstanceOf[IP]
  println(ip1 === ip2) // true
```

Answer (score 0):

I am really surprised a cast like this works at all. It shouldn't: `Array` and `IP` are two distinctly different types, you should not be able to cast one into another. Besides, `Array` is also final and you can't subclass it.

I tried playing around with this "feature", and noticed that adding anything more elaborate to it (like adding a self-type like one of the answers here suggests), crashes the (2.11) compiler ...

Besides, casting is just bad in general, because it bypasses compile-time type checks.

Don't do it. Instead, just make a wrapper class:

```
case class IPAddress(bytes: Array[Byte]) {
  override def equals(other: Any) = other match {
    case IPAddress(b) => b.sameElements(bytes)
    case _ => false
  }
}
```

Better yet, forget the wrapper too, and just use `InetAddress` instead of `IP`. You can always get bytes from it, using `.getAddress` on demand.

Comment: The cast works because the erasure of `IP` is `Array[Byte]`, so `.asInstanceOf[IP]` is the same as `.asInstanceOf[Array[Byte]]` at runtime.

Comment: @AlexeyRomanov not sure I understand: how come erasure "erases" the whole trait? Never heard of _that_ kind of erasure ... What is supposed to happen if `IPAddress` had additional methods and properties?

Comment: See the definition in https://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.12/03-types.html#type-erasure. What else could it be, given that the erasure has to be a JVM type, i.e. a class, an interface, a primitive, or an array of JVM types? Though after rereading specification of casts, I don't think it should work after all...

Comment: @AlexeyRomanov `Type erasure is a mapping from (possibly generic) types to non-generic types.`. So, erasure of `Array[Byte] with IPAddress` is `Array with IPAddress`.

Comment: It's actually misphrased, possibly because they didn't want to mention JVM in the spec to allow non-JVM implementations. By stages: 1. by the rule for compound types, the erasure of `Array[Byte] with IPAddress` is the intersection dominator of (erasure of `Array[Byte]`, erasure of `IPAddress`); 2. both `Array[Byte]` (which isn't really generic on JVM) and `IPAddress` erase to themselves; 3. the intersection dominator of (`Array[Byte]`, `IPAddress`) is `Array[Byte]`.

Comment: Ugh ... interesting ... I had no idea it did that.

Comment: Turns out I actually complained about this working before: https://github.com/scala/bug/issues/10379#issuecomment-314680914. See the previous discussion as well.

Comment: @AlexeyRomanov Really? I didn't know spec said either. Because it's a lie in more ways than one. You can _also_ do `1.asInstanceOf[String]`, and that doesn't throw ... until you actually use the result.

Comment: @Dima The reason I avoid `InetAddress` is I need to store memory efficiently. The wrapper class sounds as a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

The point of this construction is for `IP` to be represented exactly by `Array[Byte]` at runtime and to avoid boxing/unboxing even in the cases where value classes can't.

This naturally means that it has *more* limitations than value classes do, and you already can't override `equals` for them:

> [`C` may not define concrete `equals` or `hashCode` methods.](https://docs.scala-lang.org/sips/completed/value-classes.html)

You can't do it here either. You just need to give your comparison method a different name, as in Alexey Novakov's answer.

Note that technically the `asInstanceOf` cast [shouldn't work](https://github.com/scala/bug/issues/10379#issuecomment-314680914) and you should be using a refinement type e.g.

```
type IP = Array[Byte] { type T = IPAddress }
```

Comment: Hi @Alexey, could you point me any doc whic explains this syntax `type IP = Array[Byte] { type T = IPAddress }` and it's difference with the one I was using `type IP = Array[Byte] with IPAddress`... I am very new to scala, struggling to understand the differences.

Comment: It's documented at https://scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.12/03-types.html#compound-types. But all of this is advanced topics and I'd suggest not diving down into that yet. Just go with a normal case class as in Dima's answer.

Comment: Thanks @Alexey. Do you see any downside using the above syntax? All I intend it to use a simple alias and I am using the trait just to differentiate it from normal Byte array.